# Show there exist a probability measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ s.t. $X_n^2 \overset{\sim}{\to} \mu$ for $n \to \infty$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ and suppose $X_n \overset{\sim}{\to} N(0,1)$ for $n \to \infty$, where $\overset{\sim}{\to}$ denotes convergence in distribution.

Show there exist a probability measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ s.t. $X_n^2 \overset{\sim}{\to} \mu$ for $n \to \infty$ and determine $\mu$

---

So I pretty sure that probability measure I have to find is the one for the chi squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom. However I am not sure how to arrive at this. I've tried looking into the PDF for the standard normal distrubution and see if I can arrive at something the is similar to the one for the chi squareds PDF but with no luck. I don't think anyway it is what I am supposed to do. The notable theorem's introduced in the chapter where the this problem belongs are:

- Portmanteau Theorem I & II
- Helly's lemma
- Helly-Bray's Theorem
- The Continuity Theorem of Charateristic Functions.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X \sim N(0, 1)$. Since $X_n \to X$ in distribution we know that
$$ \mathbb E[f(X_n)] \to \mathbb E[f(X)] $$
as $n \to \infty$ for all bounded continuous functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (this may be under Portmanteau's theorem, depending on which version of the theorem you've learnt). Using this, can you show that
$$ \mathbb E[g(X_n^2)] \to \mathbb E[g(X^2)] . $$
as $n \to \infty$ for all bounded continuous functions $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$? Then, by another application of Portmanteau, we get that $X_n^2 \to X^2$ in distribution.

Comment: Come to think of it I do have a result stating that if $X_n \overset{\sim}{\to} X$ then $f(X_n) \overset{\sim}{\to} f(X)$ for all continous functions $f$. Couldn't I simply use $f(y)=y^2$? Also how do you actually determine what $\mu$ is?

Comment: More specifically use $f(y) = g(y^2)$. $\mu$ will be the law of $X^2$ (which is a $\chi^2_1$ distribution)